# cwac-camera showing blurry Image Preview even on Continuous Focus

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am using S3 with my 2.3 Version everything was fine and preview was ok. However after upgrade I am facing a little blurry preview. Even Continuous Focus is not removing this. The FFC is working just fine. Back Camera has this problem

Secondly, when I take an image , it takes few seconds to save the Image. The image savings are not instant like Camera App. What should be done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using S3 with my 2.3 Version everything was fine and preview was ok. However after upgrade I am facing a little blurry preview. Even Continuous Focus is not removing this. The FFC is working just fine. Back Camera has this problem

I have no idea what "a little blurry preview" means.

> Secondly, when I take an image , it takes few seconds to save the Image. The image savings are not instant like Camera App. What should be done here.

Version 0.6.0 -- due to be released soon -- should improve this, as I can now manipulate EXIF tags in memory, rather than having to make a temporary copy of the image to disk first.

Beyond that, use tools like Traceview to determine where the problem is, and if you determine that the problem is in the library, point out where, and I will see what I can do.

However, please bear in mind that matching the capabilities of any particular camera app is not one of my objectives. I am trying to create a library that works well across devices and is relatively easy to use for lightweight scenarios. In particular, it is for adding camera capabilities to non-camera apps, as a replacement for relying upon third-party camera apps via `startActivity()`. If you are writing an actual camera app, my library may or may not be deemed suitable for you.

Comment: a little blurry preview means that the Preview Is not sharp. The image taken is sharp like real image but While viewing the Preview its kind of distorted like missing pixels etc

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: You are the one choosing the preview resolution. If you are using one of my built-in algorithms, see what it is using for the resolution. Feel free to tweak your use of the algorithm, or create your own, as you see fit.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, did you find a way to fix this issue? I'm also going through the same problem. The preview is all pixelized, but the pictures are fine.